# Load data from Table with column NVARCHAR(MAX) - Cannot convert to string as value is getting truncated

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, script-component, ntext

I have a DFT with OLEDB Source - sql table with column named description data type `NVarchar(Max)`

```
select max(len(description)) from tbl_Test -- returns 10,000
```

script transformation editor to perform transformation

```
Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.TransId = Row.id;
        System.Text.UnicodeEncoding encoding = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
// i am splitting a column here into multiple records - no issues here
        byte[] bytes = Row.descr.GetBlobData(0, (int)Row.descr.Length);
        string myString = encoding.GetString(bytes);
        Output0Buffer.TransDescr = myString;
```

this code works fine if the output column is `DT_WSTR` but the problem is that the max here is `8000` hence runtime error that text gets truncated and it indeed will do which i do not want.

If i give output column as text stream `DT_NTEXT`) the above code gives error.

from this script transformation the destination is a sql table with descr as `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the script component use `DT_NTEXT` as data type for the output column, and use the following code.

```
Output0Buffer.TransDescr.AddBlobData(Row.descr.GetBlobData(0, (int)Row.descr.Length))
```

**References**

- [How to Fill NTEXT Column from Script Component - SSIS](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/35-How-to-Fill-NTEXT-Column-from-Script-Component-SSIS.html)
- [How to fix DT_Text and DT_NText Read Only in Script Component](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/be71a9b9-6e97-4e03-9a10-eb722b312d4e/how-to-fix-dttext-and-dtntext-read-only-in-script-component?forum=sqlintegrationservices)